# Timeout and unsafePerformIO

Tags: haskell, timeout, lazy-evaluation, unsafe-perform-io

I'm getting some practice in Haskell, exploring some areas I'm not familiar with, but I've ben unable to understand the behavior I get while mixing `System.Timeout` and `System.IO.Unsafe`.

I'm lazyly read an stream, with `getContents`, filtering it with a pure function, and outputting the results. A typical filter would be like:

```
import Data.List(break)
import System.Timeout(timeout)
import System.IO.Unsafe(unsafePerformIO)

main = do
    text <- getContents 
    putStr $ aFilter text
aFilter text = h ++ t where
    (h, t) = getUntil "\n" text
getUntil separator text = break (\x -> (separator!!0) == x) text
```

And with a filter like that, the program reads all stdin, as expected, and outputs to stdout. But If I do something like:

```
aFilter text = result where
    l = consumeWithTimeout (getUntil "\n" text)
    result = case l of
        Nothing -> "Timeout!\n"
        Just (h, t) -> h ++ t

consumeWithTimeout (x, y) = unsafePerformIO $! timeout 6 $! deepseq x (return (x, y))
```

I'd expect my program to instantly timeout, print the "Timeout!" message, and close. Instead, it hangs there, waiting for input.

Am I wrong in thinking that the `timeout` function is evaluated at program launch? I expect it to be, because I immediately write part of its return value to stdout, and the software does react every time I input a line. Is `unsafePerformIO` inserting some kind of lazyness into my function? Or is it inserting lazyness into the internals of `System.Timeout`?

Comment: 1) If you have to ask about `unsafePerformIO` then you shouldn't be using `unsafePerformIO`.  This example is certainly a mis-use.  Use something like the `spoon` library instead.  2) This code does not compile.  In future questions, please post the code you are actually using.

Comment: 1) But if I don't try unsafePerformIO in strange places, I can not really understand Haskell's evaluation rules. 2) Sorry about it not compiling, I completed the code and corrected the mistakes. I was trying several different things, and removed a snippet for posting.

Comment: Also, added a deepseq that forces the evaluation of x. It does not change the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is that `return $! (x, y)` does not strictly evaluate `x` or `y`.  It only evaluates the tuple constructor, which does not necessarily evaluate its fields `x` and `y`.

So what happens in your program is that `return $! (x, y)` succeeds immediately without actually trying to evaluate `x` and `y`.  The `h ++ t` part then begins to evaluate `h` which is when it finally begins to block for input.

This is, by the way, the reason you should not use `unsafePerformIO`: you cannot easily reason about when effects actually happen.

Comment: You shouldn't use `unsafePerformIO` because it's not type-safe and if you mis-use it you can get segfaults/etc.  There are other downsides too, but that's the worse part.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect

```
timeout 6 $! return $! (x, y)
```

to never trigger the timeout under normal workload. The code above does not force the evaluation of `x` and `y`. Maybe using `evaluate` will help here.

Further, using `unsafePerformIO` for this task looks rather overkill. Using `unsafePerformIO` should be done only as a last resort.